# Spring executed a query without transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I'm using spring and spring-data-jpa (hibernate as an implementation). I have the following lines of code in my controller action:

```
Flat flat = flatService.find(id);
```

FlatService is a spring service annotated with spring @Transactional annotation. So after the call to find method I should have detached entity. This entity has a lazy association to users collection. Later in my code I'm accessing this property and I was expecting lazy initialization exception to be thrown, but the collection is retrieved from the db without any exception. I enabled transaction logs, and it looks as follow:

2015-09-16 18:13:15.354 TRACE .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value ...

2015-09-16 18:13:15.354 TRACE .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value ...

2015-09-16 18:13:15.360 TRACE .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value ...

2015-09-16 18:13:15.360 TRACE .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization

**2015-09-16 18:13:15.360 TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [FlatService.find]**

2015-09-16 18:13:15.360 TRACE .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value ...

**2015-09-16 18:13:15.360 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL                        : select flat0_.id as ... - this is query for flat**

**2015-09-16 18:13:15.364 TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [FlatService.find]**

2015-09-16 18:13:15.366 TRACE .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization

2015-09-16 18:13:15.368 TRACE .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value ...

**2015-09-16 18:13:15.372 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL                        : select users0_.flat_id as flat_id6_3_0_ ... - this is query for users collection WITHOUT TRANSACTION ?**

2015-09-16 18:13:15.375 TRACE .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value ...

2015-09-16 18:13:15.556 TRACE .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value ...

2015-09-16 18:13:15.557 TRACE .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : 
Removed value ...

Can someone explain why spring was able to fetch my lazy collection without transaction?

Comment: A spring transaction is not necessary for read blocks. Your 'session' is still open and therefore you are able to read lazily.

Comment: I'm quite confused, is it specified in documentation? If my 'session' is still open why is the OpenSessionInViewFilter needed at all?

Comment: Most likely you have exactly such an `OpenSessionInViewFilter/Interceptor` active. You could debug inside the transaction manager and check the stack where it is called the first time.

Comment: But from the logs I can see that the find method is executed inside transaction boundaries and the transaction is closed after the find method completes.

Comment: OpenSessionInViewFilter is just a servlet filter that binds the  hibernate Session to the thread for the entire processing of the request. So even after the call to your method(or class) marked with @transaction has been completed, your session is still available,  in your thread. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html